# Flutter Firestore Pagination correctly fetch items

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I am trying to implement `Pagination` together with `Firestore`. For that I followed [this repo](https://github.com/olu-damilare/infinite_scroll_pagination/blob/main/lib/base_infinite_scroll/post_overview_screen.dart) and made a few adjustments, because I am working with `FireStore`. For that I wrote a query and `sort` after a `date` and also update the field of `lastDocumentId` which I take for the starting point for the next fetch-request.

This is how I adapted the code for my use-case:

```
  final CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> _notificationCollectionRef =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(BackendKeys.user.allUsers)
          .doc(AuthService.currentUser!.uid)
          .collection(BackendKeys.notifications.notifications);

  late bool _isLastPage;
  late String _lastDocumentId;
  late bool _error;
  late bool _loading;
  final int _numberOfNotificationsPerRequest = 20;
  late List<PushNotification> _notifications;
  final int _nextPageTrigger = 3;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _lastDocumentId = '';
    _notifications = [];
    _isLastPage = false;
    _loading = true;
    _error = false;
    fetchData();
  }

  Future<void> fetchData() async {
    late final QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> response;
    if (_lastDocumentId.isEmpty) {
      response = await _notificationCollectionRef
          .orderBy(
            BackendKeys.notifications.sentAtDateTimeSinceMillisecondsSinceEpoch,
          )
          .limit(_numberOfNotificationsPerRequest)
          .get();
    } else {
      response = await _notificationCollectionRef
          .orderBy(
            BackendKeys.notifications.sentAtDateTimeSinceMillisecondsSinceEpoch,
          )
          .startAfter([
            {BackendKeys.notifications.id: _lastDocumentId}
          ])
          .limit(_numberOfNotificationsPerRequest)
          .get();
    }

    List<PushNotification> notificationList = [];
    for (final response in response.docs) {
      final notificationData = response.data();
      notificationList.add(
        PushNotification.fromJson(notificationData),
      );
    }

    setState(() {
      _isLastPage = notificationList.length < _numberOfNotificationsPerRequest;
      _loading = false;
      _lastDocumentId = notificationList.last.id; // ERROR when not sorting, Bad State: no element
      _notifications.addAll(notificationList);
    });
  }

  Widget errorDialog({required double size}) {
    return Text(
      'An error occurred when fetching the notifications.',
      style: AppTextStyles.avenirNextH6Bold,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Flexible(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: sidePadding,
        ),
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: sidePadding,
              ),
              // Wrapping in SizedBox with height of buttons so
              // the header is lined up with the other views (friends & settings)
              SizedBox(
                height: touchTargetForButtons,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Inbox'.tr,
                      style: AppTextStyles.avenirNextH2Bold.copyWith(
                        color: white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      width: 20,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: sidePadding,
              ),

              Flexible(
                child: AnimatedSwitcher(
                  duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
                  child: _buildNotificationView(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildNotificationView() {
    if (_notifications.isEmpty) {
      if (_loading) {
        return _buildLoadingView();
      } else if (_error) {
        return Column(
          children: [
            const Spacer(),
            const Flexible(
              child: ErrorView(),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            RoundedCornersTextButton(
              title: 'Erneut versuchen'.tr,
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  _loading = true;
                  _error = false;
                  fetchData();
                });
              },
            ),
            const Spacer(
              flex: 2,
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _notifications.length + (_isLastPage ? 0 : 1),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        // request more data when the user has reached the trigger point.
        if (index == _notifications.length - _nextPageTrigger) {
          fetchData();
        }
        // when the user gets to the last item in the list, check whether
        // there is an error, otherwise, render a progress indicator.
        if (index == _notifications.length) {
          if (_error) {
            return Center(child: errorDialog(size: 15));
          } else {
            return const Center(
                child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ));
          }
        }

        final PushNotification notification = _notifications[index];
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: NotificationTile(
            key: Key(notification.id),
            notification: notification,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

**Problem:**

If running the code like this, I get an `error` inside `fetchData` when setting `_lastDocumentId = notificationList.last.id;` because apparently there are no items in `notificationList`.

> Bad state: no element

The weird thing is, if I set `descending: true` inside my `orderBy`-queries, I don't get the error. However that time, it always fetches the same 20 items again and again.

What am I missing here? Btw, I know there is also a package, or even several packages but I want to implement it without a package. Let me know if you need any more info!